# How to make static variable in a structure in C

Tags: c, static, structure

I want to make a structure in C with one of the structure variable having an initial default value

```
struct process{
char process_name[2];
int burst_time;
int completion_time;
int turn_around_time;
int waiting_time;
int priority;
int  arrival_time= 0;

};
```

in the above structure, i want to make arrival_time=0 but i gives me an error

```
Priority.c:11:19: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
```

Comment: It's not possible to assign `struct` members a default value in C. One workaround is to make a factory function that instances `process` and initialises it however you want.

Answer (score 2):

In C, it's not possible. You can't initialize structure members inside a structure itself. First you need to *create an instance or variable of the structure type*; only after that can you initialize a structure member. For example:

```
struct process{
        char process_name[2];
        int burst_time;
        int completion_time;
        int turn_around_time;
        int waiting_time;
        int priority;
        int  arrival_time; /* here you can't initialize */
} process_instance = { .arrival_time  = 0 }; /* first process_instance created then initialize the members */
```

And you can access like `arrival_time` like below.

```
int main(void) {
        printf("%d\'n",process_instance.arrival_time);
        return 0;
}
```

Though in **C++ (not in C)**, **structs** are almost synonymous to **classes** and can have members initialized in the constructor. For example:

```
struct process{
        int  arrival_time; /* member of structure */
        process() : arrival_time(0) {   } /*constructor */
};

int main(void) {
        process obj;
        std::cout<<obj.arrival_time;
        return 0;
}
```